# Better way to divide screen and reuse element in activity

Tags: android, layout, view

I´m a bit lost.
I´m developping my first Android app, and I´m not sure about the better way to implement some activities.

No my problem is than in my app, I have to divide the screen in two equals parts, one side for each player. Each side has two TextView, some buttons, etc, the same for both player, but one the sides rotated 180 degrees relative to the other.

What would be the better way to do that?

- Define a whole layout and repeat the same layout inside for each player? I think this would be the worst solution because the management of the listeners for the views would be duplicated and more complicated.
- Use a layout to define the player views and put it in a ListView or Table with two items/rows, using a custom adapter to unify the management of the listeners? In this case I don´t know how to divide the screen in two equals parts and fit the whole screen...
- Use fragments, defining a fragment to define the player a put it twice in the layout?
- Another idea.....

Could anyone help me and tell me the better way to do that in Android and the better way in terms of management and performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically, I have two equal layout that I want to put together in the screen, half each.
In my other layout I have used a list, with simplify the management with an adapter, but I don´t know how to split the screen in two with a list. If I define all view independently, the management and persistence is very difficult.

Which would be the better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to use the include tag in my root layout this way:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.cdp.mispartidas.actividades.Duel">

<include android:id="@+id/player0"
     android:layout_gravity="top"
     android:rotation="180"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     layout="@layout/player_duel"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>


<include android:id="@+id/player1"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     layout="@layout/player_duel"/>
```

Now my doubt is the better way to manage the listeners. In the "player_duel" layout I have two buttons that modify the content of a TextView, another button for another task, and Dialog that has to appear when click on the TextView, etc.

Now I have all the View duplicated. I can identify then by using the corresponding layout, but how I could unify the event listeners management?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

player_duel.xml

```
<LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_0"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_0"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_1"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_2"/>

</LinearLayout>

OnClickListner listener = new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){

        if(v.getParent()!=null && v.getParent().getId() == R.id.player0){

            swicth(v.getId()){

                case R.id.tv_0:

                    break

                case R.id.btn_0:

                    break

                case R.id.btn_1:

                    break

                case R.id.btn_2:

                    break

            }

        }else if(v.getParent()!=null && v.getParent().getId() == R.id.player1){
            ......
        }

    }

};
((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.player0)).findViewById(R.id.tv_0).setOnClickListener(listener);
......
```

Comment: I did not realize the possibility of identifying the parent. 
The problem of this solution is that I have to duplicate the event management. I´m going to try a ugly solution, defining aViewHolder class to inflate the views of each layout, and define a two items size array with the two layout, so in the listener manage de event depending the array index...
            View players[] = new View[2];
            players[0] = (View)findViewById( R.id.player0 );
            players[1] = (View)findViewById( R.id.player1 );

Answer (score 0):

This is the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftside"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/diceduel"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dice"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/changeduel"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_autorenew_white_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/diceresult"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/diceduel"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/playername"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scoreduel"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@+id/playername"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightside"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/sumduel"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/substractduel"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_white_24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I finally found the solution by defining the two-views array and using the "fake" viewholder. I define a listener for all the common views in the layout, and store the index as property in the constructor, so in the listener I only have to refer the proper item in the array with the index.